# Android app installation issue?

Tags: android, simulator

Guys i am working in android apps ,

it's working but problem is that when i am going to run via `simulator` it shows this message :

> `qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_24_1.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_24_1.avd/cache.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_24_1.avd/cache.img': Invalid argument`

simulator runs but app could not install :( 
I am using `intellij IDE`

Comment: Your AVD Image is corrupted . Create new avd

Comment: avd image is working, when i drop any other apk file there (simulator) then it works (mean install) and run